# Check build dependency between source files in Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio, build

I have a legacy project that is requiring rebuilds of large portions of the code base just for touching the wrong source file, and I was hoping to refactor some bits of the code to stop this build cascade from leading to large build times.

In order to focus my development effort on high-impact points, I was hoping to take a look at the build dependencies between source files to identify high fan-in and high fan-out points.

With this in mind, does Visual Studio offer any functionality that allows developers to see a graph of all build dependencies between source files?  I.e., determine which translation units will have to be rebuilt if I touch file X.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to view project dependencies but one quick and simple way is to use a native feature of Visual Studio:

1. Right click on the solution
2. Choose "Project Dependencies..."
3. Select the project from "Projects" dropdown to view it's dependencies

[image: Choose Project Dependencies...]

[image: Select project to view dependencies]

Another, more comprehensive, way would be to [create a Code Map via Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/map-dependencies-across-your-solutions?view=vs-2022) (requires Enterprise edition).

[image: Visual Studio, Enterprise Edition, Code Map]

Comment: That only goes as far as tracking dependencies between projects.  I was looking for a way to track dependencies between source files, i.e., what translation units will require rebuilding if I update file X.

Comment: @RAM I've updated the answer to provide an alternative option which is more fit for your described use case. However, this option requires Visual Studio Enterprise Edition. That said, there are likely Visual Studio Extensions that provide similar functionality.